# manually plotting a legend with markers and strings

Tags: matlab, marker, legend

I need to plot a legend separately with a set of markers and related strings without the plot. does anyone have seen a code for this?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code I finally came up with: its flexible enough for almost any application:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     Legend Generator       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% NAME     : LEGEND_GENERATOR.m
%% FUNCTION : Generates a single plot for arbitrary legend 
%% INPUTS   : set of markers and related texts as cell and figure number
%% OUTPUTS  : No output
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%                      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%     AUG 28, 2012      %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function LEGEND_GENERATOR(Marker,text,Fignum,FONTSIZE,MARKERSIZE,LWD)

% clc;clear;close all;fclose all
% Marker = {'r -*' , 'b -o' , 'g --d'};
% text = {'First Fun ' , 'Second Fun ' , 'Third Fun ' };
% FONTSIZE = 6;
% Fignum = 26;

if length(Marker)~=length(text)
    error('You should have the same number of markers as texts');
end

%% FIGURE
set(0,'defaultaxesfontsize',FONTSIZE);
figure(Fignum);clf;hold on;set(gcf,'OuterPosition',[60  90 200  250],'PaperPositionMode','auto');


Leg_TEXTS = [];
for i = 1:length(Marker)
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = 3*randn(1)*sin(x);
p = plot(x,y,Marker{i},'MarkerSize',MARKERSIZE,'LineWidth',LWD);
Leg_TEXTS = [ Leg_TEXTS ; {text{i}} ];
end


legend(Leg_TEXTS);
figure(Fignum);
set([gca;get(gca, 'children')], 'visible', 'off');

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do the same before but I was not successful. What I ended up doing is to remove some plot elements from the legend. For example:

```
h = plot(x,y); 
hasbehavior(h,'legend', false);
```

Here is another [example](http://tipstrickshowtos.blogspot.com/2012/08/removingexcluding-some-plot-elements.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can always hide the axes and all its children:

```
figure(1), clf, hold on

x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = sin(x);

p = plot(x,y);
legend('Sin(x)');

set([gca get(gca, 'children')], 'visible', 'off');
```